# apps get rejected "Apps primarily intended for use by kids under 13 must get parental permission"

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Our app is gets rejected and below is the reason from apple

> Apps primarily intended for use by kids under 13 must get parental
>   permission or use a parental gate before allowing the user to link out
>   of the app or engage in commerce

we wanted to know that if we deselect the "Made for Kids:" option and makes not changes in app functionality then will apple accept the app?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about app store policies

Answer (score 2):

Apple will probably approve the app if you deselect the "Made for Kids:" option. Although it's possible that the reviewer will decide that it's targeted at kids and reject it anyway.

However, if it is an app intended for use by kids, you should just implement a parent gate. It's the law, and it's not that hard. Much easier than paying a $250,000 fine. 
https://blog.sensortower.com/blog/2014/10/14/5-ways-to-avoid-coppa-mobile-app-fines/

Here are Apple's recommendations on acceptable types of parent gate:
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/parental-gates/

Comment: Also, be aware that the Apple Parent Gate alone won't protect you from COPPA.  http://www.iubenda.com/blog/2013/09/24/guide-coppa-mobile-apps/

Answer (score 1):

yes, your app will be accepted if you deselect "Made for kids". I am not 100% sure though but from my last 4years experience i can say that. 
Also if you want to keep app "Made for kids" than you can put a parental control for doing in-app purchase or navigation to some webpage etc. you can put a 4digit pin for activating it.
More you can found it [here](http://appsplayground.com/2013/08/19/apple-ios7-app-store-kids-category/).

Comment: Thanks for you reply: i also wanted to know that the in app description we also need to remove the lines that mention that its an app for kids?

Comment: yes, it will be better if you remove that too.

Comment: I would think the main issue is by checking Apps for Kids its going into a special kids section. The meta description is less of an issue because its going in with the rest of the adult apps anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will, Because as per apple guideline in  Kids Apps must get parental permission for e-commerce.

Your app will be accepted if you deselect "Made for kids". But note that it should follow other apple guideline.

Comment: Thanks for you reply: i also wanted to know that the in app description we also need to remove the lines that mention that its an app for kids?

Comment: @287986: Yes please remove that tline too.